# Different WebDav resource paths for same resource when using different clients

Tags: webdav, milton

I am in the process of testing a web dav enabled view my system using anumber of different clients. One particular client seems to do sometimes do strange things and I was wonder is this to be expected..

The log below shows how it has somehow mangled the path to the directory(collection in webdav speak) by including again the full path to the servlet again (look at the last line). All other clients dont do this is this primarily because its a poorly coded client that is probably broken ?

```
[org.eclipse.jetty.util.log] : REQUEST /milton/http:/127.0.0.1/milton/!renamed/ on org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector$2@59fb21
[org.eclipse.jetty.util.log] : servlet=com.bradmcevoy.http.MiltonServlet-11108810
[org.eclipse.jetty.util.log] : servlet holder=
[org.eclipse.jetty.util.log] : chain=
[com.bradmcevoy.http.HttpManager] : PROPFIND :: http://127.0.0.1:9000/milton/http:/127.0.0.1/milton/!renamed/ - http://127.0.0.1:9000/milton/http:/127.0.0.1/milton/!renamed/
[org.eclipse.jetty.util.log] : RESPONSE /milton/http:/127.0.0.1/milton/!renamed/  404
```

I have looked at the response log that the client makes available and the names are not mangled they make sense.

```
/milton/!renamed
```

and not

```
/milton/http:/127.0.0.1/milton/!renamed/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is most likely the client. - what it looks like is that the server is replying with a fully qualified URL, with scheme, host and port (http://127.0.0.1/9000), but the client is treating it as a relative uri (href - "/milton/abc") and prepending the info back on it.

Returning href's (like /milton/abc) is often used, but both are legal.